# The meaning of "up to"

Tags: meaning

> I hope you are not up to any tricks.
>
> What is he up to?

What are the meanings of "up to" in the above two sentences?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/up-to?q=to+be+up+to),

> **to be up to smth**: to be doing something, often something bad or illegal, usually secretly.
> *He looks very suspicious hanging around outside - I'm sure he **'s up to** something*

Thus, in your phrases, it means the person is asking what the other person is doing (implicitly suggesting a bad connotation).